# Is there a way for me to toggle sprinting in Minecraft 1.8.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In 1.8 PVP it's important that you stay sprinting even after getting hit, which requires you to hold down the sprint button, but most of my fingers are busy the whole time, and holding sprint is either impractical or uncomfortable, so I need the option to be able to press the sprint key once, and have Minecraft assume I want to continue sprinting forever even after getting hit until I hit it again.  Is this possible in 1.8.9?

Comment: Orange's simple mods should work: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/oranges-simplemods-collection. Alternatively, you can use Lunar, Badlion, LabyMod or many other clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### (3rd party clients)

Lunar client, Badlion client, and other clients have mods that are integrated into the client to be able to do this. This is probably the easiest way.

- [Lunar client](https://www.lunarclient.com/)
- [Badlion client](https://www.badlion.net/)

### (3rd party mods)

[Forge mods](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/better-sprinting) can also do the job.

Comment: to be clear, these will just make minecraft act like im holding down the sprint button even though im not, they wont change how the sprint behaves at all will they?  I don't want to cheat or have an unfair advantage, I just can't physically hold ctrl while hotkeying at all effectively.

Comment: @Millard People use these clients all the time on large servers like Hypxiel. Lunar is by far the most popular client, and you won't be banned for using it.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help =)